# $this->getContainer() is returning null in Symfony 3.x for Command

Tags: php, symfony-3.4, symfony3.x

I am working on a project. I have some custom validator which is basically checking some data integrity in my database before saving any new record. So for that check, I need to access the Doctrine entity manager. So below is my code.

**CustomValidator.php**

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Validator;

use ....


/**
 * Class CustomValidator
 * @package Custom\Validator
 */
class CustomValidator extends AbstractModel
{
    public function validate()
    {
        //my validation rules
    }
}
```

This AbstractModel class is basically implementing ContainerAwareInterface like below:

**AbstractModel.php**

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Model;

use ....


abstract class AbstractModel implements ContainerAwareInterface
{

     /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @return ContainerInterface
     */
    protected function getContainer()
    {
        return $this->container;
    }
    /**
     * @return ObjectManager
     */
    public function getObjectManager()
    {
        return $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    }

    /**
     * @param $entityClass
     * @return ObjectRepository
     */
    public function getRepository($entityClass)
    {
        return $this->getObjectManager()->getRepository($entityClass);
    }
}
```

Inside my `service.yml` file, i defined AbstractModel dependencies like below:

```
services:

    custom.abstract_model:
        class: Custom\Model\AbstractModel
        abstract: true
        public: true
        calls:
            - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

Now, when I am trying to run the validator, I am getting below error:

```
Call to a member function get() on null
```

Which indicates this line inside AbstractModel class.

```
return $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
```

Is there anything wrong with my implementation? I tried to search but I failed to find any useful solution.

**Update**

I believe I didn't explain 10% of the whole scenario and that 10% was the vital part. I was actually using this `CustomValidator` inside a `CustomCommand`. That was the main problem, I will explain below if anyone faces a similar problem like me later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thanks to @Trappar for answering my question. His answer is perfect for the scenario I described earlier. But I did not put whole details and the missing part was the most important part.

So, as I updated my question, I will explain the scenario now.

I had a `CustomCommand` which looked like this:

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Command;

class CustomCommand extends Command
{

    protected function configure()
    {
         //my configuration
    }


    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
            //my custom code

            $oValidator = new CustomValidator();
            $oValidator->validate($aParams);
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, in such was I was not getting the container I wanted. So, I went through some extensive research and figured out that for such cases, you have to extend `ContainerAwareCommand` and not `Command`. `ContainerAwareCommand` already extends `Command` itself and you will also get the container which will be provided by application kernel like below.

```
$this->container = $application->getKernel()->getContainer();
```

Comment: Ok, i did so. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

CustomValidator needs to have a parent service specified in the services.yaml. I believe the following would do the trick:

```
services:
    Custom\Validator\CustomValidator:
        parent: '@custom.abstract_model'
```

See: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/parent_services.html

Comment: While this is indeed the correct solution to solve the immediate problem the true issue is that one should never inject the entire container. The *right* solution would be to use constructor injection to inject just the required services into the validator, or use a `ServiceSubscriberInterface` to the same effect.

Comment: Oh absolutely and if they were using autowiring then they could use `_instanceof` and dispense with any need to declare the abstract service or mark the parent. I was just answering the question asked.